# Using RRule in Airflow

Tags: python, cron, airflow, rrule

Is it possible to use an RRule string as a schedule for Airflow? Now I use a cron expression like: `"30 2 * * *"`, but is it possible to now use an RRule expression like this to schedule my flow: `"FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=30;BYSECOND=0"`?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Cheers!

Comment: Airflow primarily relies on cron expressions for scheduling tasks and does not provide built-in support for RRule expressions. From 09-2021, Apache Airflow does not directly support using RRule. You may explore, a custom Airflow operator or sensor that interprets the RRule-like expression and generates a corresponding schedule using the Airflow scheduling mechanisms.

Comment: @Sujay Understood! Do you by any chance know a way how I can do or find this?

Comment: You could definitely make your own parser and use RRule in the code (parsed to crontab), but it will still show up as a crontab in the UI. Where do you want RRule? As an Input in the code? On the UI or as an Output elsewhere?

Comment: @scr Thanks for the information! Luckily I've figured it out and just made some Python script that converts the RRule statement to cron :)